# VirtualBox bridged adapter not working with one network

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, wireless-bridge

I have been using VirtualBox bridged adapter with some networks and it has worked right.

But a few days ago I have tried it with a new network and this time it has not worked. The only difference in this network, is that I need a username and a password to connect to it (not only the password). I don’t know if the two things can be connected.

On the Windows 8 host machine the connection works properly. On the Linux guest machine the result of the `ifconfig` command is not even showing the `inet addr`, `bcast` or `mask` information. However `ath0` is up.

Comment: What does "not worked" mean?  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

#### Shorter explanation:

If the network requires a username and password to connect and you are using “bridged” networking in the guest OS, there is no way you will ever be able to connect to that network without actually entering the username and password again in the guest OS.

#### Longer explanation:

You state this; bold emphasis is mine:

> The only difference in this network, is **that I need a username and a
>   password to connect to it** (not only the password). I don’t know if the
>   two things can be connected.

This pretty much explains what the problem is. When you setup a “bridged” network in VirtualBox it works like this as explained in [the official VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged); again bold emphasis is mine:

> With bridged networking, VirtualBox uses a device driver on your host
>   system that filters data from your physical network adapter. This
>   driver is therefore called a "net filter" driver. **This allows
>   VirtualBox to intercept data from the physical network and inject data
>   into it, effectively creating a new network interface in software.
>   When a guest is using such a new software interface, it looks to the
>   host system as though the guest were physically connected to the
>   interface using a network cable**: the host can send data to the guest
>   through that interface and receive data from it. This means that you
>   can set up routing or bridging between the guest and the rest of your
>   network.

So for all intents and purposes, when you are using “bridged” networking in your Linux guest OS in VirtualBox, it’s as if that machine is connected to the network via it’s own, non-host dependent network connector. It’s as if you simply had a second, physical machine connected to the network.

In the end, if the network you are having issues with requires a username and password pair to connect, the fact you entered those credentials to connect in the Windows 8 host OS means very little to the Linux guest OS. To get the network connection working via the Linux guest OS you would have to enter those same credentials there as well.